# angular 2 dynamic columns data table

Tags: json, angular

Currently i have a data table with hard coded column headers and filling in data.. I would like to change this table to make it dynamic so the user can pick the columns to build the table. I would like to know how or in what way i will have to change my json object to ensure dynamic column data table creation.

This is what i have tried but the data is not being loaded.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columnArray">{{col}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<table>
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let col of columnArray">
      <td *ngFor="let data of columnData"> {{col.data}} </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Currently since my data for the table comes from one object with hard coded headers here is my current working object:

```
data = [ {'id': 'idValue', 'name': 'nameValue', 'date': 'dateValue', 'description': 'descriptionValue'}, ...
]
```

but since i don't know what columns the user will pick to create the table it may be columns: id, name, description. Or columns: id, name. I need to have the data flexible so that when the user picks which ever columns to display in a table

Answer (score 2):

Working format of the data:

```
columnArray = [ {'header': 'headerValue', 'data': 'dataValue'}, ...
]
```

Then the template can be:

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr><th *ngFor="let col of columnArray">{{col.header}}></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td *ngFor="let col of columnArray"> {{col.data}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you can provide the data format more apt solution can be provided.

**EDIT#1:**

Based on your data format, I'd extract keys from an object in your data array for headers.

```
headers = Object.keys(data[0]);
```

Then the html should be:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr><th *ngFor="let col of headers">{{col}}></th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let obj of data">
         <td *ngFor="let col of headers"> {{obj[col]}} </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks - i went ahead and updated my post with how my current json looks like - let me know if your answer still applies. I am just having some trouble wrapping my head around the json structure format change.

Comment: so based on the json data u have will it be like `header: ID, data: { 1, 2, 3,4,5..}`...
`Data: {[header: id, columnData: {1, 2, 3,....}], [header: name, columnData:{sun, moon, stars,....}], ....}`

Comment: It wouldn't work for multiple rows, please check my updated answer for the data format your provided.